# JSTL cannot print a list of objects

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I am trying to print a List objects in Jsp page using JSTL but i am getting some Exception. Below is the model class for my App

```
public class ItemMaster implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1364853156929567630L;

private BigDecimal itemId;
private String itemNumber;
private String description;
private String lifeCyclePhase;
public BigDecimal getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}
public void setItemId(BigDecimal itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}
public String getItemNumber() {
    return itemNumber;
}
public void setItemNumber(String itemNumber) {
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getLifeCyclePhase() {
    return lifeCyclePhase;
}
public void setLifeCyclePhase(String lifeCyclePhase) {
    this.lifeCyclePhase = lifeCyclePhase;
}
```

Below is the controller for that List

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchQuery", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView model) {
    String[] listBox1 = request.getParameterValues("selectedright");
    List<ItemMaster> lists=itemDao.fetchRecords(listBox1);
    model.addObject("queryResult",lists);
    model.setViewName("results");    
    return model;
    }
```

Below is the snippet of my jsp page where i am trying to retrieve the values

```
<c:forEach var="queryResult" items="${queryResult}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
       <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                <td>${queryResult.itemId}</td>
                <td>${queryResult.itemNumber}</td>
                <td>${queryResult.description}</td>
                <td>${queryResult.lifeCyclePhase}</td> 
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Error which i am getting is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "itemId"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:157)
javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:70)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:167)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:936)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.results_jsp._jspService(results_jsp.java:145)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading this before going any further. Your method and variable names are a mess. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: @AlanHay I did those changes still getting the same error

Comment: You can't access BigDecimal value directly for that you need to user jstl formatter. Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to get `BigDecimal` value so you have to use the JSTL format taglib to format the display of a `BigDecimal`.

And below taglib on the JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Now retrieve the list,

```
<c:forEach var="queryResult" items="${queryResult}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
       <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
       <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${queryResult.itemId}" minFractionDigits="2"/></td>
       <td>${queryResult.itemNumber}</td>
       <td>${queryResult.description}</td>
       <td>${queryResult.lifeCyclePhase}</td> 
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Did the Changes still getting the same error..org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/results.jsp at line 48

45:     <c:forEach var="queryResult" items="${queryResult}" varStatus="status">
46:           <tr>
47:            <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
48:        <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${queryResult.itemId}" minFractionDigits="2"/></td>
49:      <td>${queryResult.itemNumber}</td>
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "itemId"
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Comment: have you add taglib on jsp

Comment: Yes i have added the taglib <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

Comment: Sorry i did a blunder i missed <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> After adding this it is working now. Thanks for your advise

Comment: This answer is incorrect. BigDecimal will be output just fine without formatting.

Comment: @AlanHay Please check above comment. This solution is working.

Comment: @user2281493 Glad it helps. Please mark it as answer

Comment: The poster notes is started working after he added the JSTL **core** library. Your answer about adding the formatting library may have provided a hint but it is not required, Your answer is incorrect and should be removed.

Comment: @AlanHay common Dude if this is the case he wasn't added core library. How foreach came to know it is list of objects. and specifically it reads all the correct values with type.